# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "repelús"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, diferencias-regionales, sinónimos

El otro día me encontré con estos dos sinóminos de *repelús*: *repeluzno* y  *repeluco*, dos palabras desconocidas para mí.

Veo que las tres tienen la misma raíz pero en el diccionario no aparece la etimología de ninguna de ellas.

Mi pregunta principal es: ¿De dónde proviene *repelús*? Pero también me interesaría saber si conocíais *repeluzno* y *repeluco* y en qué paises, regiones o tiempo se utilizan esas palabras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La palabra "**repelús**" (primera aparición: 1985) viene de:

- "[**repeluzno**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W1ImmkL)" (p. a.: 1947), significando "escalofrío"; la cual casi con toda seguridad es una derivación (posiblemente influenciada por "[repeler](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W12ubuS)", o simplemente se añade la R como refuerzo) de:

  - "[**espeluzno**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GYMnRAW)" (p. a.: 1853), con el mismo significado; la cual a su vez viene de:

    - "[**espeluznar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GYJayZm)" (p. a.: 1787):

      > 1. tr. Descomponer, desordenar el pelo de la cabeza, de la felpa, etc.
      >   2. tr. Erizar el pelo o las plumas. U. t. c. prnl.
      >   3. tr. Espantar, causar horror. U. t. c. prnl.

La etimología de "espeluznar", según [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?espeluznar), es:

> - El prefijo **es**-, derivado del latín *ex*- (hacia fuera), como en *escapar*, *escupir* y *estorbar*.
> - La palabra **pel**o, del latín *pilus*, de donde tenemos las palabras *cabello*, *pelear*, *peluca*, *peliento* y *en pelota*.
> - El verbo la**zr**ar (padecer, sufrir, martirizar), de *lacerar* y este del latín *lacerare* (trocear, hacer pedazos, quebrar, también en sentido figurado quebrantar, atormentar y hacer sufrir).
> - La terminación -**ar**, usada para nombrar verbos como en *asombrar*, *empezar* y *desvainar*.

Answer (score 5):

Yo diría que provienen de [**repeler**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W12ubuS), dada la coincidencia en la mayor parte de las letras de las palabras, y que repeler tiene la acepción:

> 4. intr. Causar repugnancia o aversión. *Hay cosas que repelen*. U. t. c. prnl.

Mientras que [**repelús**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W1FaqyI) es:

> 1. m. Temor indefinido o repugnancia que inspira algo.

Comment: No se me había ocurrido pero ahora que lo dices tiene bastante sentido, a ver si podemos encontrar algo que corrobore esa teoría.